# Saving SMTP email to IMAP Sent folder through command line. How?

Tags: email, terminal, imap

I am using the following command to login to my IMAP server:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.server.com:993
```

After typing this command in the terminal I get:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN] Server ready proxy1.mail.abc123.def456.com
```

...and from this point on, no matter what I type, the server rejects it.

```
C: SELECT INBOX
S: SELECT BAD CR sent without LF
```

I am having the hardest time finding a place online that will teach me how to take an email I have just sent with SMTP, login to IMAP and simply copy this sent email to the IMAP **Sent** folder.

Where online can I find this information? For SMTP, the information is all over the internet. For IMAP not so much as I keep getting search results about how to do it on Microsoft Outlook???!!

There are bits and pieces here on the site but no concrete functional examples I was able to find.

A bump in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you provided -crlf?  Doing this by typing it in yourself is nearly impossible because you need to know the exact byte count of the message to `APPEND` it.  This can be simply done with python’s `imaplib` though.

Comment: I have not appended it, no. That information is available online. As for the `APPEND` command you've just mentioned; now we're talking. Currently diving into RFC 3501.

Comment: The command looks like `a005 APPEND "Sent Items" {936}` where 936 is the exact byte count of what you're going to send.  This is why it's not amenable to typing in.

Comment: It is impossible to test tthis from the command line because each command needs to end with `crlf`

Comment: I do it all the time.  Maybe -crlf doesn't work in your copy of openssl, but I've done lots of poking with it in the past.  I've also used `socat` which also has a crlf tool.

Comment: Yeah. I'm on Windows... Also, IMAP is so incredibly different than SMTP. Wow.